# how to create multiple domains for image files in a website?

Tags: apache, download, dns, webserver

I read in an article that in order to maximize parallel download from a webserver, we can group our image files in separate domains. Now if I have a website with domain name www.example.com/ as my root directory and all my images are all stored inside www.example.com/pictures directory, what should i do differently in terms of storing my image files to have separate domains for my them? do i just make a bunch of new folder 1,2,3,.. instead and split my image files across those folder or what? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything with how you store your files.  You just need to edit your DNS configuration to add subdomains (like `img1.example.com`, `img2.example.com`) which all point back to your main server.  Then you can just reference your images like:

```
<img src="http://img1.example.com/pictures/pic1.png" />
<img src="http://img2.example.com/pictures/pic2.png" />
...
```

In essence, everything still resolves back to `http://www.example.com/pictures/...`, but the browser is fooled into thinking that there are multiple independent subdomains serving up the images, thus giving you more threads to work with.